# Problem in creating numbered TOC in a document

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I am making a document using word 2007. I have dumped the content and am now in formatting mode. I have to make the TOC. There perhaps is some way of auto-generating it, but for sake of learning formatting in word, I want to do it manually by myself.

Content

a

b

b1

b2

b21

b22

c

c1

c2

c3

d

Above is how it looks like. I have some basic idea of concept of styles. I have chosen content in title style. and a,b,c,d in header 1. b1,b2,c1,c2,c3 in header 2. and b21,b22 in header 3.
Now I want a continuous numbering. **So it should be like**:

Content

1) a

2) b

2.1) b1

2.2) b2

2.2.1) b21

2.2.2) b22

3) c

3.1) c1

3.2) c2

3.3) c3

4) d

I right click on a, and number it.
I remember seeing the option "**continue numbering","restart at 1**" somewhere, but when I right click on b, I was expecting to see these options and then I would click on continue numbering and as per me, this would continue the numbering from the last heading 1 style numbering.**But I don't see these options when I right click on b**.

Please help!
Thanks,

Any other commonly used word tips would be great too.

**Addition**

```
1 a

2 b

  1 b1

  2 b2

    1 b21

    2 b22

3 c

  1 c1

  2 c2

  3 c3

4 d
```

I have been able to get good indentation, but my numberings are not hierarchical. I want inner numbers to be like for b21, I want 2.2.1

Thanks,